# Matplotlib plotting different lines from one column in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a Dataframe which tracks the number of stops with a column 'ethnicity' and I want to plot the count of stops of the different ethnicities per year. My df looks something like this.

| Year | Ethnicity |
| --- | --- |
| 2001 | black |
| 2001 | white |
| 2001 | black |
| 2002 | white |
| 2002 | white |
| 2002 | black |
| 2002 | white |

I would now like to plot the total number of stops per ethnicity per year.
How would I separate the different ethnicities into different y axis.

Hope its clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group your data with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) and then count the number of occurrences.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#fake data generation 
import numpy as np
n = 50
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.choice([2001, 2002, 2004, 2007], size=n), "B": np.random.choice(list("XYZ"), size=n)})

#group df by both columns - >count elements in B for each A -> unstack the returned multiindex df for matplotlib
plot_df = df.groupby(["A", "B"]).B.count().unstack()

print(plot_df)

#pandas provides common plotting routines using matplotlib
plot_df.plot()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

```
B     X  Y  Z
A            
2001  7  3  5
2002  1  6  4
2004  2  5  6
2007  4  3  4
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to separate the different ethnicities into two different y axes using this code:

```
y_black = df[df['ethnicity'] == 'Black'].groupby(['year'])['ethnicity'].count().tolist()
y_white = df[df['ethnicity'] == 'White'].groupby(['year'])['ethnicity'].count().tolist()
```

Hope this helps somebody